# Dialog WindowLeaked during onPause()

Tags: android, android-dialog

While I am displaying the dialog and when I press Home button the app reaches onPause() but I am getting the log message "android.view.WindowLeaked". Because of this when I recreate the dialog in onCreate() (App reaches here after onDestroy()) I could see the dialog appears in a different size which is not the same size as it was before. Any Clue ?

```
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): Activity memory.game.collection.free.ClassicalMemoryGame has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4131ee90 that was originally added here
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity memory.game.collection.free.ClassicalMemoryGame has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4131ee90 that was originally added here
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:349)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at memory.game.collection.free.ClassicalMemoryGame.showDialogLevelCleared(ClassicalMemoryGame.java:2332)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at memory.game.collection.free.ClassicalMemoryGame$DelayLastCard.onPostExecute(ClassicalMemoryGame.java:2654)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at memory.game.collection.free.ClassicalMemoryGame$DelayLastCard.onPostExecute(ClassicalMemoryGame.java:1)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-05 09:25:49.581: E/WindowManager(11732): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you need to dismiss the dialog when you exit the app or move to an onPause state ..

Comment: Ok. I will try this. But what may be the reason for he different sized dialog when recreating after onDestroy()

Comment: may be the orientation changes for a while while the onDestroy gets called - i am afraid but then this is just a guess :)